# How to efficiently count the number of defined pointers?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have the following C++ code:

```
Some_class * temp1 = findTemp1(...); // returns NULL or a valid pointer
Some_class * temp2 = findTemp2(...); // returns NULL or a valid pointer
Some_class * temp3 = findTemp3(...); // returns NULL or a valid pointer
```

Now I would like to count how many of these returned a valid pointer (0, 1, 2 or 3).

The only way I can think of is just to test them one by one:

```
int count = 0;
if (temp1)
   count++;
if (temp2)
   count++;
if (temp3)
   count++;
```

For 3 pointers, it's not too bad, but it doesn't scale well. Is there a more efficient way assuming I don't redefine the findTempN funcitons (to maybe pass in the counter)?

---

Thanks a lot for your quick replies! No, I am not going to change the code, I was just wondering what were my other options. I also realized that I cannot be asking for something "scalable" if I am using distinct literals like that to define the 3 pointers. Of course, I didn't think of the things you replied :)

Answer (score 11):

Well, since this is C++ we can go crazy in the quest for terseness... for example:

```
int count = !!temp1 + !!temp2 + !!temp3;
```

**Update:** I probably owe Ivan an explanation of what's going on here.

Assuming `temp` is any kind of pointer, `!temp` forces the coercion of the pointer's value to `bool` (we want to do this) and negates the result (this is a side effect that we do not want). This results in `true` if the pointer is null and `false` if the pointer is not null, which is the opposite of what we 'd like. So we add another `!` in front to negate the result again.

This leaves us with adding three `bool` values which coerces them to `int` and performs the addition, whereupon we have our final result.

You might find it easier to understand the completely equivalent

```
int count = (bool)temp1 + (bool)temp2 + (bool)temp3;
```

which I did not use because typing `!!` is three characters shorter than `(bool)` (*note: you might think that this is a nice trick, but when writing code it is a **really bad idea** to make decisions based on how many characters you have to type*).

The moral of the story is that doing this type of thing can be called either clever or atrocious, depending on who you ask -- but in C++ there has traditionally been high tolerance for atrocities.

Note that *if the pointers were in some type of collection to begin with*, you could write **much better-looking code** using [`std::count_if`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/464xhzk3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), e.g.:

```
bool isNotNull(void* ptr) {
    return ptr != 0;
}

std::vector<Some_class*> vec;
vec.push_back(temp1);
vec.push_back(temp2);
vec.push_back(temp3);

int count = std::count_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), isNotNull);
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/BBlns)**.

Or, as very cleverly suggested by MSalters in the comments, you can lose the `isNotNull` function by counting the pointers which *are* 0 and subtracting this from the number of all pointers -- but for this, you will need to somehow know what this number is (easy if they are in a `vector`):

```
int count = vec.size() - std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/nJqpT)**.

Comment: and better still, put all these pointers into a container of some sort and loop over it accumulating !!p

Comment: This is only more efficient if you define efficient as what the OP wants, which is scalability. But this is the answer to this question, so +1

Comment: @jk: I hope you're kidding. JFTR: `std::count_if` is much, much better than the `!!p` ugliness. At least, note that the absolutely equivalent `(p?1:0)` adds a little bit of readability.

Comment: @Christopher that's only equivalent in result. And now that I see it, that `vector` method looks dreadful.

Comment: You'd be better of counting the ones that _are_ 0: `int count = vec.size() - std::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), NULL);`

Comment: @MSalters: Good one, I edited the answer to incorporate it. Also makes the [C++11 example](http://www.ideone.com/f4VTl) with a lambda instead of `isNotNull` superfluous.

Comment: @Seth: What is the difference between “equivalent” and “equivalent in result”? In this particular case, I don't even expect to find a compiler emitting different machine code instructions, and in general, it's often surprisingly difficult to say a priori which version will run faster on which compiler at which settings. *Code is supposed to say what you want to achieve.* (I do agree MSalters' suggestion is a good one.)

Comment: Sure, typing `!!` is shorter than `(int)`, or even better, `static_cast<int>()`. However, we don't write code to be as short as possible, we write code to be as clear as possible. `!!` completely obfuscates the meaning here. You could also use `== 9` and get the same effect as `!!` if you want to avoid the cast.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig: I also totally agree with you that anything else other than the `count` variants is ugly and possibly bad code. Casting the pointers to `bool` and adding would be acceptable as long as there's only a few. But this is C++ and the fact that we 're even *discussing* `!!` speaks for itself.

Comment: @Christopher for instance, `int sum = 0; for (int i = 10; i > 0; --i) sum += i;` and `int sum = 10 * 11 / 2;` are equivalent in result, but not "absolutely equivalent."

Comment: @BillyONeal: That was intended as tongue-in-cheek (see above comment). But I don't mind the downvote if you feel the answer as a whole deserves one.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Also, casting to `int` is actually a bug -- it's funny that both of us did not catch it at once. So there you go, `!!` for the win. ;-)

Comment: @Seth: Agreed, we can use different algorithms to achieve the same effect. A compiler might replace both of your codes with the equivalent of `int sum=55;`, but it's certainly possible to hide that option from the optimizing step. In the case from above, the algorithm is the same, though, and even *considering* how to squeeze out a cycle or two is premature optimization, i.e., the root of all evil. YMMV, of course.

Comment: @Jon: 1. It certainly doesn't look tongue-in-cheek in your answer. 2. No, use `!= 0` instead. Your intention is not to negate something twice, it is to compare it against null. Or cast to `bool`, though note that produces a performance warning on MSVC.

Comment: @BillyONeal: I still think that anything starting with "we can go crazy in the quest for terseness" should not be taken as a serious suggestion. Of course `!= 0` is the way to go if one wants to add, but it's still longer than `!!`.

Comment: @Jon: Your answer does not say "We can go crazy in the quest for terseness." Your answer recommends `!!var`, then explains why it works, then says you chose that because it's shorter. In complete deadpan technical explanation.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Allow me to disagree, it does say that re craziness/terseness. You will also see that I added the tech later because I thought that the OP might not even understand what's going on. But as I said, I 'm happy with life and we don't have to argue really. Thank you for your input, which I fully agree with.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define N 3
typedef Some_class *PointerGenerator(...);
PointerGenerator funcs[N];
func[0] = &findTemp1;
func[1] = &findTemp2;
func[2] = &findTemp3;

Some_class *ptrs[N];
for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) ptrs[i] = func[i]();
for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) { if(ptrs[i]) ++count; }
```

C++0x variant:

```
int count = std::count_if(ptrs, ptrs + N, [](const Some_class *i) -> bool { return i != NULL; } );
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is Good Enough, don't mess with it.

Introducing subtlety is a common novice error, don't do it.

That said, `NULL` is a valid pointer value, and you can do e.g. `count += !!temp1 + !!temp2 + !!temp3` (but that would be newbie obfuscation, do not actually do that).

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: What he has is good enough for three pointers, but as he said, it doesn't scale.  What if he has 100 pointers?  (Note that the `!!temp1 + !!temp2...` obfuscation doesn't scale either.)

Comment: @James: well I think that part of the question, with n different functions, is pure fantasy. not realistic. but of course the thing to do if one really had to deal with such lunacy, would be to put those function pointers in some kind of collection, such as an array. i think in general about half of the questions here on SO are at least partially made-up. so little of it makes sense!

Comment: @BlackBear: Added an explanation in my own answer above.

Comment: @Alf It would be nice if the people asking questions asked something realistic:-).  In this case, as you say, 100's of functions isn't realistic---it's not scalable either.  But the idea of having a number of pointers to something, and wanting to count the valid ones, could occur in a more realistic context.  (Or maybe not.  In the cases I can think of, you'd probably be putting the pointers into a container, and you simply wouldn't insert the null pointers.  So the count would be the size of the container.)

Answer (score 0):

If all of the pointers are the same type, put the pointers in a table,
or if you can't do that, make a table of pointers to the pointers.  Then 
use `std::count` or `std::count_if`.  Something like:

```
SomeClass** pointerTable[] =
{
    &temp1,
    &temp2,
    &temp3,
    //  ...
};

struct IndirectIsNoNull
{
    bool operator()( SomeClass** p ) const
    {
        return *p != NULL;
    }
};

//  ...
int validPointerCount = std::count_if( begin( pointerTable ),
                                       end( pointerTable ),
                                       IndirectIsNoNull() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a `static` counter.

```
template<typename T>
struct ValidPointer
{
  static unsigned int count;
};
template<typename T>
unsigned int ValidPointer<T>::count = 0;

template<typename T>
static void isValid (const T* const p)
{
  if(p)
    ValidPointer<T*>::count++;
}
```

Usage:

```
isValid(temp1);
isValid(temp2);
...
```

At any point of time, if you want to retrieve then,

```
unsigned int count = ValidPointer<Some_class*>::count;
```

This code can be improved as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the pointers afterwards? `temp` suggests otherwise. In that case, you can eliminate those:

```
int count = 0;
if (findTemp1())
   count++;
if (findTemp2())
   count++;
if (findTemp3())
   count++;
```